# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error upon login

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-7, asp.net-2.0, iis-7.5

I'm getting the above error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" while i'm trying to login to my website which is hosted on IIS 7.5.. I can't get any error details in the Event Viewer either so I'm really having a hard time knowing what to do.

In any case, here are the details of my website:
Granted access to the website's physical path / folder on the following users and groups: IUSR, NETWORK SERVICE, IIS_IUSRS, aside from the default SYSTEM, Administrators, and my local workstation account

Granted db_owner permission for the database to the following SQL Server Logins:
NT AUTHORITY\IUSR, NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, aside from the default NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, and my local workstation account.

The Identity of the Application Pool used is LocalSystem (because of an error that occured minutes before, Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool').

Please help me.. I need this done as soon as possible.. thank you very much..

Comment: *Object reference not set to an instance of an object* is most likely a **coding** error rather than an authentication error. You will need to provide more details than what you have so far.

Comment: There is a lovely tool called a debugger, attach it to the process and find out where you made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you think you have provided all possible permissions and authentication, double check connection string.